# Is there a way to disable force flag in reboot command

Tags: bash, reboot, bashrc

I want to prevent execution of `reboot -f`, Is there any way we can either disable the force flag itself or simply ignore the force flag and redirect the usual reboot?

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is.